# Returning sequential numbers

Tags: mysql

Assume Col contains system name "Apple". Col B has a bunch of ID's associated with system in Col A. These ID's mean something wrt the system. Col C has the timestamp at which these ID's are generated by the system.

This is the query I wrote to obtain the above data:

```
SELECT Name, ID, time
FROM Xtable
WHERE (Name='Apple') AND ID in ('1', '2', '3', '4')
GROUP BY Name, ID, time
```

The problem with this query is that it returns rows as long as it contains one of the above numbers (not necessarily in a sequence)

Output of the above query:

```
Apple   3    12/1/2010 11:04 AM 
Apple   4    12/1/2010 11:58 AM
Apple   1    12/1/2010 11:00 AM
Apple   1    12/1/2010 11:01 AM
Apple   1    12/1/2010 09:05 AM
Apple   2    12/1/2010 09:10 AM
Apple   3    12/1/2010 09:40 AM 
Apple   4    12/1/2010 10:00 AM
Apple   2    12/4/2010 03:25 PM 
Apple   1    12/4/2010 12:47 PM
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

I want to tweak it such that it returns values in all three columns only when the IDs in Column B occur in a sequence (1,2,3,4). I want this information because the sequential IDs represent a set of events that I'm using to extract some information.

Comment: `SORT by Id` doesn't work for ya?

Comment: Event ID 2 could occur before Event ID 1, in which case you'd want the records excluded?

Comment: is the sequence based on the time field? or based on how it was inserted

Comment: Its based on the timestamp. But sometimes event 1 and 2 appear for a couple of rows and after a while/in between, you'd see all 4 events which is what I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if Event ID 2 occurs before ID 1. All I want is all 4 ID's (1, 2, 3, and 4) to occur in consecutive rows. The IDs mean something only if all them appear together. I mean, if there are any repeating IDs like: 3, 3, 4, 2, 1; I want the first 3 to be excluded from the output.